# Added class with a hover pseudo element version not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bar here - http://jsfiddle.net/3pxnjocp/4/ - that gets an image background when rolled over. When the small box is clicked I want to change the bar to become red and stay red when rolled over.  Does anyone see why the code I have is not doing that?  The box click adds a class to the bar with a hover pseudo element version, that even has a `!important`, but the original hover style, with the image background,  is chosen instead.

Thanks.

```
$(function(){
    var flag=false;
    $('#flag').click( function() {
        if(!flag) {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('#box').addClass('alwaysRed');
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            $('#flag').css('background-color', 'white');
            $('#box').removeClass('alwaysRed');
            flag=false;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'none'` shouldn't be quoted in `background-image`.

```
#box.alwaysRed:hover {
  background-image: none;     // no !important required
}
```

is all that's needed:

```js
var flag=false;

$('#flag').click( function() {
  if(!flag) {
    $('#flag').css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#box').addClass('alwaysRed');
    flag = true;
  }
  else {
    $('#flag').css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#box').removeClass('alwaysRed');
    flag=false;
  }
})
```

```css
#box {
    width:100px;
    height:26px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
#box:hover{
  background-image: url('http://s3.postimg.org/wkct91733/bar_Background.png');
}
#flag {
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
}
#box.alwaysRed {
    background-color:red;
}

#box.alwaysRed:hover {
    background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/3pxnjocp/5/

```
#box.alwaysRed {
    background:red !important;
}
```

Your jQuery code is working as intended, just your css is not as it should be.